# RuntimeError: Cannot write() after finish(). May be caused by using async operations without the @asynchronous decorator

Tags: python, tornado

I am getting the above error while making a post request in the tornado server .

I have a class like

```
class RestRequestHandler(RequestHandler):

    def async_get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def async_post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

The above class I am importing into another py file

```
class get_question_details(RestRequestHandler):

    def async_post(self, activity_id, attempt_id, quiz_id, question_id,
                   questionusage_id, slot, user_name, courseshortname):
        client = get_moodle_client()
```

When I am making this request I am getting the warning like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 421, in _run_callback
    callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gameonapi/server/rest.py", line 142, in async_post_callback
    self.return_ok(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gameonapi/server/rest.py", line 214, in return_ok
    self.write (result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 489, in write
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot write() after finish().  May be caused "
RuntimeError: Cannot write() after finish().  May be caused by using async operations without the @asynchronous decorator.
```

From the error I understood that problem causing because I am not using the tornado `@asynchronous` but after using that also still I am getting the same warning .

Please tell me what might I am doing wrong here .

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use the `@asynchronous`decorator the `self.finish()` function would be called automatically before the function is complete

What you should have is

```
class RestRequestHandler(RequestHandler):

@tornado.web.asynchronous
def async_get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.write('ok')
    self.finish()

@tornado.web.asynchronous
def async_post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.write('ok')
    self.finish()
```

This way the system gives you the chances to write out whatever you wish to write. When finished writing you will need to call the `self.finish` method to tell the system you are done.

Comment: There is a good post on this issue here:  https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1385

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should register Post method for your class, because I dont see how tornado may handle POST request in your way.
Check this question.
[How to use POST method in Tornado?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367981/how-to-use-post-method-in-tornado)